# Application-defined or Object defined error when adding a new series to a chart (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to dynamically add new chart series to a single chart, from a single table of data on that page. However, during the .XValues command, I keep getting

> Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

I'm using the following code:

```
Sub addseries()

Dim endpt1 As Range
Dim endpt2 As Range
Dim Address1 As Range
Dim Address2 As Range

For x = 2 To (Sheets.Count - 1)
Cells(1, 2 * x - 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set endpt1 = ActiveCell
Cells(1, 2 * x).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set endpt2 = ActiveCell
Range(Cells(2, 2 * x - 1), endpt1).Select
Set Address1 = Selection
Range(Cells(2, 2 * x), endpt2).Select
Set Address2 = Selection

Debug.Print ("Last Row1: " & endpt1.Address & " Last Row2: " & endpt2.Address)
Debug.Print "x Range: " & Address1.Address
Debug.Print "Value Range: " & Address2.Address
'Add new series
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
'Set ranges for new series
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2 * x)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).XValues = "='Merged Plot'!Address1.Address()"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Values = "='Merged Plot'!Address2.Address()"


Next x
End sub
```

And these are the values that appear in the immediate window:

```
Last Row1: $C$62 Last Row2: $D$62
x Range: $C$2:$C$62
Value Range: $D$2:$D$62
```

Comment: X starts at 2 so you need to subtract 1 to get the current series e.g. ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x - 1).Name

Comment: But what is this? "='Merged Plot'!Address1.Address()"   The Address1 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this. I would make a lot of other changes but the 2 things currently you should be looking at are:

1) X starts at 2 but new series commence at 1 so remove 1 from X e.g.   `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x - 1).Values`

2)C̶o̶n̶c̶a̶t̶e̶n̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶r̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶ ̶e̶.̶g̶.̶ ̶ ̶`̶"̶=̶'̶M̶e̶r̶g̶e̶d̶ ̶P̶l̶o̶t̶'̶!̶"̶ ̶&̶ ̶A̶d̶d̶r̶e̶s̶s̶2̶.̶A̶d̶d̶r̶e̶s̶s̶`̶ ̶  Set the address part as follows  `"=" & Address1.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)`   .

Thanks to @Shai Rado for notes on using `Address1.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)`

```
Option Explicit

Sub addseries()

    Dim endpt1 As Range
    Dim endpt2 As Range
    Dim Address1 As Range
    Dim Address2 As Range

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 2 To (Sheets.Count - 1)

        With ActiveSheet

            .Cells(1, 2 * x - 1).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Set endpt1 = ActiveCell
            .Cells(1, 2 * x).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Set endpt2 = ActiveCell
            .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * x - 1), endpt1).Select
            Set Address1 = Selection
            .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * x), endpt2).Select
            Set Address2 = Selection

            Debug.Print ("Last Row1: " & endpt1.Address & " Last Row2: " & endpt2.Address)
            Debug.Print "x Range: " & Address1.Address
            Debug.Print "Value Range: " & Address2.Address

            With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
             .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
             .SeriesCollection(x - 1).Name = .Cells(1, 2 * x).Value
             .SeriesCollection(x - 1).XValues = "=" & Address1.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
            .SeriesCollection(x - 1).Values = "=" & Address2.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
           End With

        End With

    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, if you use `Address1.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)` and the 4th parameter being `xlExternal` will add the worksheet name (if it's being pulled from a different sheet)

Comment: Also, `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate` and `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` ? ;)

Comment: Hello Mr Rado - please feel free to edit that in. Are you saying that there may be a problem with the above or that is could be improved.? I am puzzling my way through the comment...sorry

Comment: Lol. I didn't try to fix all the problems Mr Shado :-)

Comment: Funny :) , your code should work, but there are shorter and more reliable to achieve the desired result (I Upvoted)

Comment: @ShaiRado You are gonna mention the .selects aren't you ? :-) And that I could compress all that down into two range objects

Comment: LOL, no, just. A couple of comments, don't want to take over your answer

Comment: It would be a good learning point for me ( /everyone!) if you would post a condensed version answer of your own.

Comment: Naaahhh, not necessarily shorter, most likely longer with a lot of setting of objects

Comment: Thanks everybody!
Shai Rado & QHarr- the new address with xlExternal did the trick. You are both amazing. 
And I know that the rest of the code is a complete mess - I've only been using VBA for two weeks lol

Answer (score 0):

"=" & Address1.Address(False, False, xlA1, **xlExternal**) did the trick!